# Elegant proof of an elementary result in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, alternative-proof

I've been reading Hoffman Kunze, and I came across this theorem (*theorem $9$*) which has a long and tedious proof. I've been wondering wether there could be a more elegant proof.

> ***Theorem 9.*** Let $e$ be an elementary row operation and let $E$ be the $m\times m$ elementary matrix $E = e(I)$. Then, for every $m \times n$ matrix $A$,
>   $$e(A) = EA.$$

To be more explicit about what I mean by 'elegant' proof, I'm looking for a proof where we don't actually have to consider each of the 3 elementary row operations separately.

Answer (score 1):

$$e(A)=e(IA)=e(I)A=EA.$$

In fact, in general, you can say

$$e(BA)=e(B)A.$$

(This is justified below. The intuition behind this is that applying a row operation to a matrix and then multiplying it with another matrix is the same as applying a row operation to their product.)

Alternatively, you can reduce the three cases in the proof you're given to scalar multiplication (which is obvious) and adding rows, since a row change is just a combination of these operations.

Comment: Your second equality in the first line is not justified at all.

Comment: You need to give a proper explanation otherwise I can also claim that the Theorem 9 is as obvious as your equality.

Comment: Fair enough. Letting $C=AB=(c_{ij})$, $r_k,c_k$ denote the row and column vectors of $A$ and $B$ respectively, we have $c_{ij}=r_i \cdot c_j$. So multiplying by a scalar $k$ just yields $kc_{ij}=kr_i \cdot c_j$, and adding the $k^{th}$ row to the $i^{th}$ one just yields a row of the following entries, letting $j$ range: $$c_{ij}+c_{kj}=r_i \cdot c_j+r_k \cdot c_j=(r_i+r_k)\cdot c_j.$$

Comment: Yes that's right. If you add that to your answer it will be good, because although the reasoning is the same as proving Theorem 9 directly, the generalization shows that it's not so ad-hoc. Furthermore, you might want to mention that the **intuition** is that if $e$ is any operation that is a combination of only scalings or swappings of rows, then clearly applying $e$ to $A$ first before multiplying by $B$ is the same as applying $e$ to the product $AB$, since the position of a row in the answer is controlled by the position of the corresponding row in $A$ alone.

Comment: Oh and don't use $k$ for two different things. =)